# what is the best way to embed program logic that seats in some algorithm class into pyqt4 user interface

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, recommendation-engine

```
class SomNetwork(object):

    def __init__(self, dataset):
        # some parameters that are not important here
        pass

    def one_step_learn(self, k, sigma_0, gamma_0, alfa, mcolor,population_of_ids):
        pass

    def learn(self):
        pass

class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_QSom()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.frame = MyFrame(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
        self.frame.start()
        self.show()

class MyFrame(QtGui.QFrame):

    simulationSpeed = 5000

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Ramka, self).__init__(parent)

        self.init_Board()

    def init_Board(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()
```

I would like to be able to interact with SomNetwork class in order to be able to call its methods from within inside of the MyFrame class methods. Are there any special design patterns that would suit this example the most or should I just add instance of the class as a field to the MyFrame class.

Thanks of your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question is heading towards this, but for your network you could try to subclass a `QtCore.QObject` instead. On the whole you should instance your network as a member of your `QMainWindow`, so your frame and the net can interact via signals and slots.

... By the way, there is a little flaw in your code, when you call the constructor of a `QWidget` in the subclass of a `QMainWindow`.